# Click an element within section tag

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The Element is inside  tag but many ways tried couldn't click on it.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Login to Register']"))).click();
```

and

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Login to Register']"));
JavascriptExecutor jsEx= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsEx.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

**Here is the html:**

```
<div id="requestRegistrationWidget">
     <a id="requestLocationLogin" href="/user/login?destination=%2Fsearch%2Flocations%2Fwidget%3Fparam1%3D006046-0619_1565278200_11000000%26param2%3D3" class="use-ajax login-popup-form" data-dialog-type="modal">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100% !important;" type="button" value="Login to Register"></input>
    </a>
      <!-- registerSession == 3 and registerAnyActiveSession == 1 case (2) --> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: https://preview.queenslibrary.org/search/calendar?searchField=*&category=calendar&searchFilter=
Just click any card you'll see Quick View the right side an specific section is not workable. Thanks.

Comment: https://preview.queenslibrary.org/search/calendar?searchField=*&category=calendar&searchFilter=
" click on search put star click ''Calendar" Radio Button and click search from the right side
Just click any card you'll see Quick View the right side an specific section is not workable. Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce with your steps above, but it's possible your selector isn't selecting what you think it is and that's why it's not clickable.

Comment: Navigation --> click Search from the top right after 'Donate' Button than put * on ' keyword' and select 'Calendar' Radio Button than click on Search Button from the right. After that click on any of cards you'll see in Quick View pane at  right side of the card this specific portion I can't click.- Thanks. @DMart

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a try with the below code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("requestLocationLogin"))).click();
```

Comment: Select audience
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value='Login to Register']"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value='Login to Register']"}

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are facing this issue on chrome.
Try this, it works for me.

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Its just hitting the "Enter" button on the element.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Login to Register** as the element is [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) enabled element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.use-ajax.login-popup-form#requestLocationLogin>input.btn.btn-primary[value='Login to Register']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='use-ajax login-popup-form' and @id='requestLocationLogin']/input[@class='btn btn-primary' and @value='Login to Register']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: xpath and cssSelector tried but couldn't click on AJAX element !